# dplyr'ish version of applying function to random rows

Tags: r, dplyr

## Background

I'm generating some sample data that I want to use to show some simple analytical operations on Spark. Spark context is not relevant here.

### Sample data

The data I'm using looks as follows:

```
library("tidy verse")
set.seed(123)
dta_ts <-
  tibble(category = sample(LETTERS[1:4], replace = TRUE, size = 1e5)) %>% 
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(ref_dte = sample(
    x = seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'), as.Date('2016-12-30'), by = "1 day"),
    size = n(),
    replace = TRUE
  )) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(rand_val = rpois(n(), lambda = 10))
```

## Question

I would like to insert some outliers to the data. In base R this is easy to achieve using:

```
# Add outliers
for (i in sample(1:nrow(dta_ts), 50)) {
  dta_ts[i,3] <- sample(1e4:1e6, 1)
}
```

### Problem

The provided solution is, arguably, inefficient and inelegant. I would like to find *dplyr'ish way of achieving the same result.*. I'm aware of `sample_n` and `sample_frac` but I'm not interested in sampling data, only in accessing random selection row. The ideal solution would function as a follow-up addition to te pipeline below:

```
... %>%
mutate(rand_val = rpois(n(), lambda = 10)) %>%
# On random outliers are created
```

Comment: The for loop is not needed: `dta_ts[sample.int(nrow(dta_ts), size = 50), 3] <- sample(1e4:1e6, size = 50)` would be efficient and elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate random `n` values from 1 to number of rows in the data and `replace` them with `n` high values from  `1e4:1e6`.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 50

dta_ts %>%
    mutate(rand_val = replace(rand_val, sample(n(), n), sample(1e4:1e6, n)))
```

You could continue this in the same chain from your attempt, I am showing it differently here.

You can use the same logic in base R as well.

```
transform(dta_ts, 
    rand_val = replace(rand_val, sample(nrow(dta_ts), n), sample(1e4:1e6, n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 50
dta_ts %>%
     mutate(rand_val = case_when(row_number() %in% sample(n(), n) ~ sample(1e4:1e6),  TRUE ~ rand_val))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- sample(nrow(dta_ts), n)
dta_ts$rand_ts[i,1] <- sample(1e4:1e6, n)
```